# Edit true/false depending on the checkbox value in Webix

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dom-events, webix

I've created an editable Webix datatable with the column of checkboxes.

Wondering how can I set `edit` function to the datatable row depending on the value of the checkbox?
Perhaps, I should use

```
$$("dataTable").attachEvent("onBeforeEditStart", function(. . .){. . .});
```

But I'm a bit confused what exactly I need to write.
And here goes the [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/39ab06be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works via simple logic:

```
function(id){
  if(this.getItem(id).ch1){
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Check this: http://webix.com/snippet/098c09dd